# Change text inside of material design checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

```
<CheckBox x:Name="inactivity_cb" Content="X"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionDarkCheckBox}" Click="cb_Click"/>
```

Hello, I have checkbox with materialdesign style. When Checked is true then text in check box is "✔" when false then it is "X" (based on 'Content="X"').

I would like to change "✔" to something else without editing that style somehow. I just want it to this single CheckBox. Any tips?
Thank you so much for all answers and have a great day guys :)

Comment: Not having seen the style itself, this is a bit off the cuff, but it sounds like you should create a style based-on the existing one (literally set the `BasedOn` property to the existing style resource) and then just override the appropriate setters.  This might require you to supply a new template in your style but you can probably copy the existing one and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is a bit old but I case someone need the answer

You need to add this property to change the checked display,

```
materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent="-"
```

note that you can also directly put an icon (check the material design sample for the icon list)

```
materialDesign:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Hand}"
```

And the icon syntax is also valid for the content property